# SQL Query to count number of records must match total number of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables as

**Result Master**

```
+------+-------------+
| QnID | Description |
+------+-------------+
|    1 | Qn1         |
|    2 | Qn2         |
|    3 | Qn3         |
|    4 | Qn4         |
|    5 | Qn5         |
+------+-------------+
```

**Result Details**

```
+----+------+--------+--------+
| ID | QnID | TCDesc | Result |
+----+------+--------+--------+
|  1 |    1 | TC1    | PASS   |
|  2 |    1 | TC2    | FAIL   |
|  3 |    1 | TC3    | PASS   |
|  4 |    2 | TC1    | PASS   |
|  5 |    3 | TC1    | PASS   |
|  6 |    3 | TC1    | PASS   |
|  7 |    3 | TC3    | PASS   |
+----+------+--------+--------+
```

I need a query which will return following result:

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | QnID | Result |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 |    2 | PASS   |
|  2 |    3 | PASS   |
|  3 |    4 | ERROR  |
|  4 |    5 | ERROR  |
+----+------+--------+
```

Conditions:
each question will have different number of testcase "ResultDetails", I need to select questions for which all the test case get passsed (number of entries for a particular question must be same as number of test cases passed for the same) or Error (ResultDetail doesn't have an entry for a question).

Can anyone please help me with a query, thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have elaborated my question can you please help me with that

Comment: Are your columns really named 1, 2, Qn1, TC1, and Pass? That's highly non-descriptive. What's the column connection the master and details tables?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: @ZoharPeled sorry, updated my table structure, can you please look at it now

Answer (score 1):

You can get the desired results using a common table expression and conditional aggregation.

First, create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
DECLARE @ResultMaster AS TABLE
(
    QnID int, 
    Description char(3)
);

INSERT INTO @ResultMaster (QnID, Description) VALUES
(1, 'Qn1'),
(2, 'Qn2'),
(3, 'Qn3'),
(4, 'Qn4'),
(5, 'Qn5');

DECLARE @ResultDetails AS TABLE
(
    ID int, 
    QnID int, 
    TCDesc char(3),
    Result char(4)
);

INSERT INTO @ResultDetails VALUES
(1, 1, 'TC1', 'PASS'),
(2, 1, 'TC2', 'FAIL'),
(3, 1, 'TC3', 'PASS'),
(4, 2, 'TC1', 'PASS'),
(5, 3, 'TC1', 'PASS'),
(6, 3, 'TC1', 'PASS'),
(7, 3, 'TC3', 'PASS');
```

Then, use a common table expression to calculate the number of pass details and a simple count to get the number of total details:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT  M.QnId, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 'PASS' THEN 1 END) As CountPass, 
        COUNT(Result) As CountDetails
FROM @ResultMaster As M
LEFT JOIN @ResultDetails As D ON M.QnId = D.QnId
GROUP BY M.QnId
)
```

Then, select from that cte:

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY QnId) AS Id,
        QnId,
        CASE WHEN CountDetails = 0 THEN 
            'ERROR'
        ELSE
            'PASS'
        END
FROM CTE
WHERE CountPass = CountDetails
```

Results:

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | QnID | Result |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 |    2 | PASS   |
|  2 |    3 | PASS   |
|  3 |    4 | ERROR  |
|  4 |    5 | ERROR  |
+----+------+--------+
```

[You can see a live demo on rextester.](http://rextester.com/KWVRL91757)